# Remove duplicates from a LIST and create a new list based on the initial position of the items

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, math

I have a list of n items (objects), the items have been weighted based on the order listed, having a higher weight the items that comes first in the list. 
Some of items are duplicated, so I am trying to leave one single instance of that item in the list and allocate it to a position in the list based on the average of the weights e.g: (ItemA_weight1 + ItemA_weight 2+ .../ Amount of items in the list)

For instance, having the following list:

```
 skillsViewModel = new List<SkillViewModel>()
        {
            new SkillViewModel()
            {
                Name = "a",
                Weight = 6
            },

            new SkillViewModel()
            {
                Name = "b",
                Weight = 5
            },

            new SkillViewModel()
            {
                Name = "c",
                Weight = 4
            },
            new SkillViewModel()
            {
                Name = "a",
                Weight = 3
            },
            new SkillViewModel()
            {
                Name = "c",
                Weight = 2
            },
            new SkillViewModel()
            {
                Name = "e",
                Weight = 1
            }

        };
```

the items "a" and "c" are duplicated, so I need to get a new list where all the items are distinct and where only and item from the dupes exists one, so it will produce the below list. BTW each item in the list has a new weight based on his position and the total amount of items of the new the list:

New List:

```
 skillsViewModel = new List<SkillViewModel>()
        {

            new SkillViewModel()
            {
                Name = "b",
                Weight = 4
            },

            new SkillViewModel()
            {
                Name = "c",
                Weight = 3
            },
            new SkillViewModel()
            {
                Name = "a",
                Weight = 2
            },

            new SkillViewModel()
            {
                Name = "e",
                Weight = 1
            }

        };
```

the new positions for "a" and "c" have  been calculated like that:
Sum of the initial weights and dividing between the amount of items in the list.

e.g:

```
                var averageWeight = 0;
                foreach (var d in dupes)
                {

                    averageWeight = averageWeight + d.Weight;
                }


"a" position = averageWeight = (int)Math.Ceiling((Decimal)averageWeight / 
(Decimal)skillsViewModel.Count());
```

`a=1.5` => So it is rounded to `2`

Same for item "c" = 1 => so position 1, I need to fill the left positions in the list with the rest of the items based on its previous position.

The problem I am having is that if I rounded the operation to calculate the position of one of the dupes, it can be the same position other duplicated item can get because of its weights.

What is a good general algorithm to implement this behavior, i am using C#?

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach has the disadvantage, that the property `Weight` depends on the context but the object itself never "knows" about its context, so the property has to be set from outside. 
And the second disadvantage you mentioned already: two objects can't have the same position.

You could sort the objects in an array of weights:

```
int[] weights;

weights[1][] = new SkillViewModel(){ ... }
weights[1][] = new SkillViewModel(){ ... }

weights[2][] = new SkillViewModel(){ ... }
weights[2][] = new SkillViewModel(){ ... }
```

You could still make the array more complicated but detailed by adding the position as key too (excuse, my code might by syntactically wrong, I'm not programming in `C#`):

```
int[] weights;

int weights[1][] = position;
weights[1][1] = new SkillViewModel(){ ... }
weights[1][2] = new SkillViewModel(){ ... }

int weights[2][] = position;
weights[2][4] = new SkillViewModel(){ ... }
weights[2][3] = new SkillViewModel(){ ... }
```

Having an array like this, the context like `Position` or `Weight` can be totally unknown inside each `SkillViewModel` itself and it could consist only of property `name`:

```
    new SkillViewModel(){
        Name = 'e';
    }
```

Surely it's possible to create a resembling structure in a List-object instead of an array, but I think you get the point that the context is determined outside the `SkillViewModel`s and not required anymore as property inside.

---

Another approach has the same disadvantage I wrote in the first sentence, but allows further details: you could add a property `position`:

```
    new SkillViewModel()
    {
        Name = "e",
        Position = 1,
        Weight = 1
    }
```

Like this `Position` and `Weight` are disentangled from the physical position in the code and also can get the same values like another object.

Edit:
Perhaps you've to forget the idea, that the sorting of the elements is so important and deciding. Assign the desired / required values to each object and for sorting them by weights or position you can have different methods for sorting and creating a `view`.